# Matrix-Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c

I'm writing a C code including matrix multiplication and I'm using 3 nested loops for that operation. So, does anyone know how we can improve that code by removing one of the nested loops?

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
        for (k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k)
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "improve"? Performance? Readability? If you want performance, then you might want to try taking a look at cache optimizations. Those will likely produce more speedup than the sub-cubic algorithms unless you reach massive sizes.

Comment: Really not the type of thing to write yourself if you have the choice.  The basic loop structure is fine (there are sub O(n^3) methods but more advanced study needed).   However, even these simple loops can be made much better by using higher precision accumulations, parallel instructions, and cache awareness.   If possible, find a library.

Comment: I am sure that will reduce the readability and maintenance of code.

Answer (score 3):

Matrix multiplication for dense matrices has O(n^3). This can be accelerated by using [Strassen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) to O(n^(2.8)) or [Coppersmith-Winogar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) to O(n^(2.37)).

Comment: @Kos: Thanks, just noticed this myself, didn't knew about Coppersmith before.

Comment: On the same Wikipedia page: "However, unlike the Strassen algorithm, [Coppersmith-Winograd] is not used in practice because it only provides an advantage for matrices so large that they cannot be processed by modern hardware."

Answer (score 1):

Strassen algorithm is a classic one to try.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm

It is more complicated than writing three loops and the overall speed gain might not show through if the matrix size is small.

As far as I know, Mathematica and Matlab use the three nested loop multiplication for small matrices and switch to Strassen for larger ones.

There are other algorithms that theoretically perform better asymptotically, but unless you are doing very very large matrix multiplication, I don't think it will help that much.